# Unable to use EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption

Tags: c#, encryption, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption. I am unable to retrieve records from the database. I am getting the encryption padding error while reading the records as per the example.

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/54663388/data-encryption-in-data-layer-with-asp-net-core-entity-framework

PS. @Eastrall
I am unable to add comments for my query on 
[Data Encryption in Data Layer with ASP.NET Core Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663388/data-encryption-in-data-layer-with-asp-net-core-entity-framework)
so added a new question here.

Comment: Hi, Rock, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you include the code you're using to retrieve records from the database as well as the specific error message you're getting as part of this post?

Comment: Hey, The issue mentioned here got resolved by restricting the keys used and storing them. So as the same key is used always. But I am trying to use it with DBModelBuilder which doesn't seem feasible due to the restrictions in the DBContext class code.

Comment: That’s interesting. I’m glad you were able to identify the cause. I recommend you post that as an answer to your own question and, in a couple of days, mark it as the accepted answer. (Not only can you do that, but it’s encouraged, as it marks the question as answered so future people with similar problems know you found a solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the AES256Bits as block size and set PaddingMode.PKCS7.  Make sure you save the keys and use the same key for subsequent read and write operations. This will stop any errors while parsing the records as well.